# Set theory : Anti-symmetric but transitive (proof)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

The exam practice question is as follows:

- We call a relation $R$ **anti-reflexive** iff $\forall a \in A :   
     (a,a) \notin R$ and **anti-symmetric** iff $\forall a,b \in A : (a,b)
     \in R \rightarrow (b,a) \notin R$.
        Prove or refute that any anti-reflexive and transitive relation is    also anti-symmetric.

I know it works because: $A = {(1,2),(2,3),(1,3)}$ is anti-reflexive, transitive and anti-symmetric - but I am struggling to prove this using **only** the definitions of the set relations.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that there are $a,b \in Dom(R)$. Such that $(a, b) \in R$ and $(b, a) \in R$. If the relation is transitive then it follows that $(a, a) \in R$. Here is the contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put $c=a$ into the definition of transitivity...